# docker entrypoint script fails to run

Tags: docker

I have a script `startScript.sh` that I want to run after the docker container completely starts (including loading all services that the container is supposed to start)

After that I want to run a script: `startScript.sh`

This is what I do:

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 <docker image name> " /bin/bash -c ./startScript.sh"
```

However this gives me an error:

```
WFLYSRV0073: Invalid option '/bin/bash'
```

Even tried different shells still same error. Even tried passing just the script file name. Still did not help.

Note: I know that the above file is in the container in the root folder: /
In fact I once entered the container by doing: `sudo docker exec` and manually ran that script file and it worked.
But when I try to automatically do it as above, it does not work for me.

Some questions:
1. Please suggest what could be the issue.
2. I want to run that script after the container has started completely and is up and running - including all the services that are part of it. Is this the right way to even do it? Or does this try to run while  the container is starting up?

Comment: what is your base image? it might not have bash installed.

Comment: are you in windows?

Comment: "Services", plural?  Can you provide your image's Dockerfile?  Can you run this initialization task from another container after the main container's service has started up (as you might, for example, run database migrations for a Web app)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass arguments after the image name, you are not modifying the entrypoint, but the command (CMD). It seems your image has `WFLYSRV0073` as entrypoint, which makes the actual executed binary be your entrypoint, with your command as arguments. Which makes `WFLYSRV0073` fail when trying to parse `/bin/bash` as an argument.

To run just your script, you could override the image's entrypoint with an empty string, making it run your command's first element. Notice I also remove the quotes, or else Docker will search for a binary with the name containing spaces, which of course doesn't exist.

```
sudo docker run --entrypoint "" -p 8080:8080 <docker image name> /bin/bash -c ./startScript.sh
```

However this is probably not what you want: it won't run what the image should actually be running, only your setup script. The correct thing to do here is to modify the image's Dockerfile to run the setup script as the entrypoint, and at the end of it run the script's current entrypoint (the actual thing you want to run).

Alternatively, if you do not control the image you are running, you can use `FROM <the current image>` in a new Dockerfile to build another image based on it, setting the entrypoint to your script.

Edit:

An example of how the above can be done can be seen in [MariaDB's entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/master/10.5/docker-entrypoint.sh): you first start a temporary server, run your setup, then restart it, running the definitive service (which is the CMD) at the end.

The above solutions are good in case you want to perform initialization for an image, but if you just want to be able to run a script for development reasons instead of doing it consistently on the image's entrypoint, you can copy it to your container and then use `docker exec <container name> your-command and-arguments` to run it.

Comment: Thanks @Leonardo. But if I set entrypoint in the Dockerfile using the current image in FROM, won't it override the existing entry steps in the original image? Or will the entrypoint steps in the original image happen and then once they are all completed, my script will run?

Comment: I tried this. What happens is this: my script runs some script that invoke the service created in the original docker image. When I run my script, it looks like the service is not up and running. My script is running before that itself. What I want to do: let thee original docker container get created first - let it start all its services. Aftr that my script should run.

Comment: I added a bit more information, with an example of how to do what I described, and a "quick hack" way to do it if you need it just for testing.

Comment: Doing what I had described, you'd have to do the service execution in your script. Either like mariaDB, starting a temporary server, doing setup, then restarting it with the definitive options, or just starting the service and running your setup.

Comment: Thanks! I started the docker container and then ran exec script. That worked for me.

Comment: I ran : sudo docker exec -it $(sudo docker ps -lq) /bin/bash setup_script.sh after starting the doker container. I had to put a sleep for 10s before calling docker exec to give time for the container and its services to get fully instantiated

Comment: Instead of a sleep you could also consider having the start of your script check if the service is online in a loop to avoid race conditions. Do note that while running things with docker exec is very practical for development and testing, if that is something that should always run on startup, you should really consider making a custom entrypoint. Also, if you can please consider accepting the anwer :)